# Can setTimeout ever return 0 as the id?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I am writing a check to see if a timeout is active. I was thinking of doing this:

```
var a = setTimeout(fn, 10);
// ... Other code ... where clearTimeout(a) can be called and set to null
if (a != null)
{
   // do soemthing
}
```

I was wondering if it would ever be possible that a will be 0. In that case I would use `a !== null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: 0 isn't the same as null, (0 == null) would be false in every case';

if you want to test 'a' against something: define 'a' first and later assign the settimeout to 'a'. then check against the type of 'a'. If its 'undefined', the timer hasn't triggered yet

Comment: My mistake :) I didn't check, but yes `0 != null` always. I expected them to be equal in Javascript, considering equalities like '' and 0 - but this is not the case.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @GrantGryczan and yet, back in the days when the dinosaurs were still walking among us, Aishwar accepted it as the answer. While i indeed agree that my answer doesn't answer the title, it did fix the problem. The answer of Felix Kling is however the correct answer.

Answer (score 41):

[It shouldn't](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers), given this:

```
handle = window . setTimeout( handler [, timeout [, arguments ] ] )
```

> Let `handle` be a user-agent-defined integer that is **greater than zero** that will identify the timeout to be set by this call.

Comment: @Alin: I came to this site via https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout, where it says that it is part of DOM Level 0. So I thought this actually older than HTML5, but maybe I misinterpreting something.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. You did answer my question, though the accepted answer addressed my concern.

Comment: @Aishwar, but null is not a number, it is not good to mix types, even in js

Comment: Looks like the text has changed, but still the same takeaway for this question: "_If previousId was given, let id be previousId; otherwise, let id be an implementation-defined integer that is greater than zero and does not already exist in global's map of active timers._"

Answer (score 15):

The specifications from Microsoft, Sun and Mozilla just say that it will return an integer. So `0` may be included.

It may be possible (and probable) that some implementations exclude `0` but you shouldn't rely on that. You should go with the `!==`.

**To summarize:** Although probably all browser exclude `0` from the IDs returned by `setTimeout`, you should not write your code with that in mind especially when all your have to do is add an extra `=`.

Comment: +1 Thanks. You did answer my question, though the accepted answer addressed my concern.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers will return an int starting at 1 and incrementing for each call of setTimeout so in theory it could never be 0.

But keep in mind that *this is not really a requirement of the spec*, just a convention browsers tend to follow.  See the accepted answer here for more details:  [setInterval/setTimeout return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940120/setinterval-settimeout-return-value)

Comment: It's apparently part of the HTML5 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html).  Pre-HTML5 it was just a convention.