# Issue with intervals and click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a project where we have to come up with a game where the square will change position based on `math.random`

I have two problems

1. it seems its running multiple instances of the function, as after a few cycles of the square repositioning - it will go bonkers and move all over the place in what seems like random intervals.
2. second problem is that i'm having a hard time getting the square div to registre the second time i click on it.

Link to JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ybpdjujb/

```
$(document).ready(function test() {
    $(document).on('click', '#target', function clicker() {
        $('#target').css('left', randPosX);
        $('#target').css('top', randPosY);
        clearInterval(fire)
        timeLeft = 2;
    });

    //Random
    var bodyWidth = $("#playArea").width();
    var bodyHeight = $("#playArea").height();
    var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth / 1.1));
    var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight / 1.1));

    //TIMER
    var timeLeft = 2;
    var elem = document.getElementById('time');
    var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

    function countdown() {
        if (timeLeft == 0) {
            doSomething();
            timeLeft = 5;
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
            timeLeft--;
        }
    }

    function doSomething() {
        $('#target').css('left', randPosX);
        $('#target').css('top', randPosY);
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }

    var fire = setInterval(test, 2000);
});
```

Comment: What is the objective of this game? To keep on changing the square's position and when the user clicks on it stop moving?

Comment: @raghav710 Yeah, sorry my bad for not explaining it well enough. the objective is to, press the square before the timer runs out which will then spawn in a new location. - if you manage to click the square, it will then spawn in a new location. with the timer resetting.

Comment: looking at the code, even if you dont press the square within the given time, it does move to a new location. I would like to understand the difference between a click and a no-click. What differs?

Comment: @raghav710 , yeah, i'm just bad at explaining. bear with me here:

the objective is: are you fast enough to press the square - you get 2 seconds - if the time runs out, it moves to a new spot. but if you manage to press it, it ALSO moves to a new spot but then giving you 1 point for success (i need to implement some sort of scoring before this makes sense)

Comment: ohhh.... got it now. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: is this what you want? If yes, I can post a detailed answer explaining what changes I made to get it working: https://jsfiddle.net/raghav_s/1mdcfmrr/1/

Comment: @raghav710 , Yes! , thank you so much Raghav! If you're not too pressed for time, an explaination would be much appreciated.

Comment: @ Keano can you check my answer and suggest any additions I can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The reason the square was going bonkers is that you were doing `setInterval()` in two places. One where you do `var fire = setInterval(test, 2000);` and one where you do `var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);`. Remove one of these (and fix a few other things) and your code starts working.

But, we don't want to stop there, working code can soon become difficult to modify if not structured properly. So for your benefit and that of the programmer community let's see how we can refactor this code. I believe this will be useful for future coding (and debugging) exercises. If this is already common knowledge to you, consider this a refresher :)

**Step 1: Put only what is required in** `document.ready`

Here's a quick question. What do you want to do when the document is ready? **Three** things

1. Display the square
2. Setup the onclick handler
3. Start the timer

Let's keep only those and move the rest outside the `document.ready` block. One thing you have rightly done is comment regions of code you feel should go together, let's convert them into functions! While doing this we notice the stray `setInterval()` at the end of the file which we can remove.
Your code should now look like this (refactoring that is done is explained below):

```
function doSomething() {
    positionSquareRandomly();
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timeLeft = 2;
    startTimer();
}

function positionSquareRandomly(){
    var bodyWidth = $("#playArea").width();
    var bodyHeight = $("#playArea").height();
    var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth / 1.1));
    var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight / 1.1));
    $('#target').css('left', randPosX);
    $('#target').css('top', randPosY);
}

function startTimer(){
    var timeLeft = 2;
    var elem = document.getElementById('time');
    var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == 0) {
        doSomething();
    } else {
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
        timeLeft--;
    }
}

function clicker() {
    doSomething();
}

$(document).ready(function test() {
    //Display square
    positionSquareRandomly();

    // Setup timer
    startTimer();

    // Setup click handler
    $(document).on('click', '#target', clicker);

});
```

**Step 2: Refactor I**

1. `positionSquareRandomly()` should get the co-ordinates *and* display the square. So we move the `$('#target').css(..)` calls to that method
2. Now when we do that `clicker()` and `doSomething()` look pretty similar, so `clicker()` now calls `doSomething()` which in turn positions the square and resets the timer i.e. clear the interval, reset `timeLeft` and call `startTimer()`.
3. The `clearInterval(fire)` is gone as its not needed. `timeLeft = 5` is also gone.

**Step 3: Refactor II**

Nice, but now we see that nothing happens! Press **F12** to open the Developer console, Click on the **Console** tab. The error I see is `Uncaught ReferenceError: timeLeft is not defined`. This is because `timeLeft` is declared in `startTimer()` but we are trying to use it in `countdown()` too. We fix that by declaring `timeLeft` above all functions (making it global).

Similarly, put the `var elem` declaration at the top.

Declare `var timerId = 0` at the top. The Id returned by `setInterval()` is always non-zero so this is a good initial value. ([Set timeout example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943553/can-settimeout-ever-return-0-as-the-id))

That's it!, add some useful `elem.innerHTML` in the `if` portion of countdown and we get this code.

```
var timeLeft = 2;
var elem = document.getElementById('time');
var timerId = 0;

function doSomething() {
    positionSquareRandomly();
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timeLeft = 2;
    startTimer();
}

function positionSquareRandomly(){
    var bodyWidth = $("#playArea").width();
    var bodyHeight = $("#playArea").height();
    var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth / 1.1));
    var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight / 1.1));
    $('#target').css('left', randPosX);
    $('#target').css('top', randPosY);
}

function startTimer(){
    timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == 0) {
        elem.innerHTML = '0 seconds remaining';
        doSomething();
    }
    else {
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
        timeLeft--;
    }
}

function clicker() {
    doSomething();
}

$(document).ready(function test() {
    //Display square
    positionSquareRandomly();

    // Setup timer
    startTimer();

        // Setup click handler
    $(document).on('click', '#target', clicker);

});
```

There's a few things more we can do, but now I believe the code is clear, concise and above all, maintainable.