# How many times on earth does setTimeout execute?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I know this may be an old question. But I'm really confused after a few googling.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval), I learn the setTimeout will execute forever,

but from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout), I learn it will execute only once.

What's strange is that when I test it in browser console, I happen to see it keeps executing..

[image]

But sometimes it only execute once:

[image]

The same code gives different result. Anyone know why?

**EDITED:**
I now can believe setTimeout executes only once, but how to explain the first screenshot of my test?

Comment: *"From this question, I learn the setTimeout will execute forever"*: If you are referring to the accepted answer, I think it actually refers to the function defined in the question, not `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 5):

**setTimeout** will only execute **once**.

The code in the stackoverflow question you linked to keeps executing because it is **recursive**. The setTimeout call, calls itself.

Comment: its tricky in my case doing like this $(".btn-new-order").trigger('change'); was causing lot of issues

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` does *not* execute forever, though as demonstrated in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval), you can emulate `setInterval` by calling `setTimeout` again in the function you pass to `setTimeout`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/940148/1881136) explains that the return value from `setTimeout`/`setInterval` is one that you can use to refer to the timer later to cancel the timeout.