# setInterval and clearInterval in JavaScript as a single thread language

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval, single-threaded

I have a problem understanding the way in which `setInterval` and `clearInterval` work in JavaScript.

I have read different articles on these two functions but I am still confused.

Given the fact that JavaScript is `single thread` then when we call `test=setInterval(function(){}, t)` we will schedule our function to be executed every `t` miliseconds. Unless we `clearInterval(test)`.

- What does that mean? Does it mean that by `clearInterval` we `cancle` the `setInterval` which is already in the queue of JavaScript?
- What would happen if we `setInterval` several times but `clearInterval` only once?
- Can we `clearInterval` in `setInterval`?
- How JavaScript handles the scheduled process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does that mean? Does it mean that by clearInterval we cancle the
>   setInterval which is already in the queue of JavaScript?

Yes.

> What would happen if we setInterval several times but clearInterval
>   only once?

Each `setInterval` returns a handle that you can use with `clearInterval` to stop that specific timer. Each timer is handled individually.

> Can we clearInterval in setInterval?

Yes.

> How JavaScript handles the scheduled process?

Pretty much like any other event. An event is triggered at an interval, and the event handler calls the callback function that you specify. If some script is running when the event is triggered, then the event will be handled when the control is returned to the browser.

Comment: Thanks. For the second question - Do you mean that if I use `handler=setInterval(function(){}, t)` 5 times and then use `clearInterval(handler)`, then I would have 4 scheduled process inside the queue?

Comment: @Suo6613 yes. Each call to `setInterval()` establishes a distinct, independent timer.

Comment: @Suo6613 also you're not really scheduling "processes", you're scheduling *events*, and the function you pass to `setInterval()` is the event handler. (They're not "events" likc "click" or whatever, but it's more similar to that than to the concept of a "process".)

Comment: @Suo6613: If you call `setInterval` five times you get five timers and one handle for each timer. If you store them in the same varible then each one will ovewrite the previous, and you have five timers and one handle. Using the handle with `clearInterval` will only stop the timer that you have a handle to, leaving you with the four timers running that you no longer have the handles to.

Comment: When there is no handler for the remaining four, then they won't be executed or they cannot be stopped?

Comment: @Suo6613: They can't be stopped. The handle (not handler) is not needed for it to run, it's only used for stopping it.

Comment: thanks a lot. Just one more question! can we `clearInterval` when the function inside the `setInterval` is in middle of its working? Not within the fuction. Let's say using some callback functions which is independent from the function inside the `setInterval`

Comment: @Suo6613: Yes, you can use `clearInterval` at any time, from anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Each `setInterval` call [returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940120/setinterval-settimeout-return-value) a unique value that when passed into `clearInterval` stops the specific call of `setInterval` that returned that value.

So in your example, `test` that was returned when calling `setInterval` will be different than a value returned from a another `setInterval` or `setTimeout` call. Therefore when doing `clearInterval(test);` only the call that returned `test` will stop running on interval.