# Why does this countdown clock code return an undefined string?

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a really simple Javascript clock that would countdown to 0 from a time that the user specifies, but for some reason it keeps returning 'undefined' as a string. Here is the source of the clock:

```js
function startTimer(duration) {
  desap = duration - (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
  var timer = desap,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs";

    if (--timer < 0) {
      display = "Ended";
    }
    return display;
  }, 1000);
}

document.write(startTimer(999999999999999))
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsjhcku8/)

Comment: Your function `startTimer` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, I would lean toward using the `.textContent` javascript property, rather than `document.write`:

```js
var displayTimer = document.getElementsByClassName('display-timer')[0];

function startTimer(duration) {

  setInterval(function() {
    var timer = duration - (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
    var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    var display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs";

    if (--timer < 0) {
      display = "Ended";
    }

    displayTimer.textContent = display;

  }, 1000);
}

window.addEventListener('load',function(){startTimer(999999999999999);},false);
```

```html
<div class="display-timer">
</div>
```

Comment: This is an even better solution of what I thought about, but even though it's working on the snippet, my localhost will continue to say "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'displayTimer.textContent = display')". Why does that happen?

Comment: Have you compared what you have locally to the snippet above, line by line?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same, I think it is because I'm calling the function inside the callback function of a Google maps API.

Answer (score 0):

It does not return `undefined` as string. It just returns `undefined` and that is because there is no `return` statement in your code.

The return statement is inside callback of `setInterval`

#### Sample code

```js
function startTimer(duration) {
  desap = duration - (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
  var timer = desap,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs";

    if (--timer < 0) {
      display = "Ended";
    }
    return display;
  }, 1000);
}

var a = startTimer(999999999999999);
document.write("Value of a is: ", a, " and type is: ", typeof(a))
```

If you wish to get timer, you can try something like this:

```js
function startTimer(duration) {
  desap = duration - (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
  var timer = desap,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs";

    if (--timer < 0) {
      display = "Ended";
    }
    return display;
  }, 1000);
}

var a = startTimer(999999999999999);
document.write("Value of a is: ", a, " and type is: ", typeof(a))
```

And if you wish to show timer on UI, you should use callbacks:

```js
function startTimer(duration, callback) {
  desap = duration - (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
  var timer = desap,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs";

    if (--timer < 0) {
      display = "Ended";
    }
    if(callback) callback(display);
  }, 1000);
}

var a = startTimer(999999999999999, notify);
function notify(str){
  document.getElementById("timerContent").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<div id="timerContent"></div>
```

#### Reference

- [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)
- [How to return value from setInterval/setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940120/setinterval-settimeout-return-value)

Comment: Your snippet returns 'undefined undefined'

Comment: type of undefined is undefined. @Fraaaan I have updated my answer. Hope it helps now.

Comment: @Downvoter, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the `document.write` inside the interval?

```js
function startTimer(duration) {
  var desap = duration - (new Date().getTime()) / 1000;

  var timer = desap;

  var minutes = 0;
  var seconds = 0;
  var display = "";

  setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)      
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs <br/>";
    if (--timer < 0)
      display = "Ended";

    document.write(display);
  }, 1000);  
}

startTimer(999999999999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet, I disabled document.write because JSFiddle disallow the use of this function, instead I used console.log to display the output. You can change that later.

**Edit :** You are getting an undefined error because you are using an **anonymous function** and outside "setInterval" you don't have any return for your main function "**startTimer**"

```js
 function startTimer(duration) {
  desap = duration - (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
  var timer = desap, minutes, seconds;
    
setInterval(function () {
   minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
   seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
   minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
   seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
   display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs";
   
   if (--timer < 0) {
    display = "Ended";
  }
    //document.write(display);
console.log(display);
  return display;
  }, 1000);

 }

startTimer(999999999999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

In OP code `document.write(startTimer(999999999999999))` , you haven't return any variable so it will undefined ,even if you return it will get only one times because startTimer is only one time runs.`setInterval` has inside function so write `document.write` inside `setInterval function of startTime` will be valid .

```
<div id="timing"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var show = document.getElementById("timing");
    function startTimer(duration) {
        desap = duration -  1000;
        var timer = desap;
        clock = setInterval(function() {    
                var minutes, seconds,display;
                 minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                display = "Ends in " + minutes + " mins and " + seconds + " secs";
                if (--timer < 0) {
                  clearInterval(clock);
                  display = "Ended";
                }
                else{
                show.innerHTML = display;    
               }   
              },1000);     
}

startTimer(999999999999999);
</script>
```