# clear interval from redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My middleware looks like

```js
export const timerMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === "START_TIMER") {
    // console.log("timer");
    action.interval = setInterval(
      () => store.dispatch({ type: "TICK", currentTime: Date.now() }),
      1000
    );
    debugger;
  } else if (action.type === "STOP_TIMER") {
    //console.log(store);
    debugger;
    console.log(action.interval);
    clearInterval(action.interval);
  }
  next(action);
};
```

on Start timer the clock is ticking, but on stop_timer i loose the reference of setInterval. so unable to stop the clock.
what i am missing here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/xrmnwr7y8z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to mutate the action. Each time you get into the middleware you will have a new action, so your interval will be lost. action.interval also isn't in line with the flux standard action schema. You could have a let outside of your middleware like

```
let interval;
const timerMiddleware ...
```

and then go

```
interval = setInterval // interval will now be a number which is a reference to your interval
```

Then when it's time to clear it

```
clearInterval(interval)
```

But if you wanted to be more immutable, you do have access to the store in your middleware

```
const interval = setInterval(...)
store.dispatch({
    type: "SET_YOUR_INTERVAL"
    payload: interval
});
```

Then in your reducer you can store that under `state.someInterval` or whatever

```
case "SET_YOUR_INTERVAL":
    return {
        someInterval: action.payload
    }
```

and then by the time you get back into the middleware and the action is "STOP_TIMER" you can use store.getState() to get the reference to the current state. Then you can go `clearInterval(currentState.someInterval)`

and then store.dispatch you can dispatch an action to clean up the interval in state

For more info about the return values of setTimeout and setInterval: [setInterval/setTimeout return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940120/setinterval-settimeout-return-value)

Comment: I was just following this [guide](https://www.codementor.io/vkarpov/beginner-s-guide-to-redux-middleware-du107uyud).